# Cassandra Downed Host Retry (Hector)

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

Can someone assist me in understanding and troubleshooting this issue? I do not know what is causing Hector to fail when it tries to connect to the Cassandra cluster.

How can I find out where the issue is?

```
0    [main] INFO  me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService  - Downed     Host Retry service started with queue size 10 and retry delay 30s
168  [main] INFO  me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.JmxMonitor  - Registering JMX         me.prettyprint.cassandra.service_keyspace-name:ServiceType=hector,MonitorType=hector
399  [main] INFO  me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ConfigurableConsistencyLevel  - READ     ConsistencyLevel set to QUORUM for ColumnFamily Files
400  [main] INFO  me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ConfigurableConsistencyLevel  - WRITE     ConsistencyLevel set to QUORUM for ColumnFamily Files
406  [main] INFO  me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ConfigurableConsistencyLevel  - READ     ConsistencyLevel set to QUORUM for ColumnFamily FileList
407  [main] INFO  me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ConfigurableConsistencyLevel  - WRITE ConsistencyLevel set to QUORUM for ColumnFamily FileList
```

Answer (score 1):

From the trace it seems you are using QUORUM as consistency level. Try to use ONE and see if it works. It seems that one or more of the nodes that should satisfy your request are down. Use noderool ring/status or see if any node is down in your cluster.